# expo-av Video not showing up on iOS but working on Android

Tags: ios, react-native, expo-av

Video and video player is loading fine on Android, but on iOS nothing is rendered. I'm using Video from expo-av.

I tried adding height and width to the view , tried

```
 source={{ uri: post.videoURL + ".mp4" }}
```

as these solved the problem in other SO posts, but they didn't work for me. What else would you suggest?

```
let videoPlayerRef = useRef(null);
...
```

```
            <View>
              <Video
                ref={videoPlayerRef}
                style={{
                  width: 350,
                  height: 200,
                }}
                resizeMode={Video.RESIZE_MODE_COVER}
                shouldPlay={true}
                useNativeControls
                isLooping={false}
                usePoster
                rate={1.0}
                volume={1.0}
                isMuted={false}
                onPlaybackStatusUpdate={(videoStatus) =>
                  setVideoStatus(() => videoStatus)
                }
                source={{ uri: post.videoURL }}
              />
            </View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was video format. Check what video format is uploaded/ played, guys. The video I was trying to play on iOS was neither of these:  .m4v, .mp4, and .mov . Also the videos I was trying to upload in my app were .mov and that also caused problems  - they didn't upload

Comment: thanks, I was having some strange issues with playback on Android and this helped.  I converted my video to H.264 MP4, which plays well on both platforms.

Comment: Actually, I have checked the video formats and all of them are `.mp4`. Any other ideas for this issue?

Comment: I have the same issue (no video or controls) and have tried .mp4, .mp3, and .m4v files. I know it has something to do with my server because when I put in a big buck bunny URL (https://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4) it works fine. I even uploaded that exact video to my server and it still doesn't work. I thought it might be because my server doesn't use file extensions but I modified it to support that and still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with ios version, but my problem was the name of the files, when I removed the spaces from the name everything worked fine.