# Native playback controls are missing on iOS while using expo av

Tags: react-native, expo, video-player, expo-av

I am using React native expo AV and native playback controls missing on iOS 14.0.1. But it works on Android normally. How can I fix it?

```
           <ScrollView style={{ marginTop: 10 }}>
              <Card>
                <Card.Title subtitle={item.name} />
                <Card.Content>
                  <VedioPlayer
                    ref={video}
                    style={styles.video}
                    source={{
                      uri: item.source
                    }}
                    // eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-boolean-value
                    useNativeControls={true}
                    resizeMode='cover'
                    isLooping
                    onPlaybackStatusUpdate={status => setStatus(() => status)}
                  />
                </Card.Content>
              </Card>
            </ScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: Check below link hope it will help https://stackoverflow.com/a/71469507/12489279

Comment: the video is in mp4 format: https://d23dyxeqlo5psv.cloudfront.net/big_buck_bunny.mp4

Comment: ok , and have you pass  `useNativeControls={true}`  to video player ?

Comment: yes, plz check the code above